# About root distribution of complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

We have some Laurent polynomial $f(z)$ with powers of $z$ from $a$ to $-b$, $a,b$ be positive integers.

Consider the equation $f(z)-E=0$.

Let $P$ be the set defined by:  $z'\in P$ $\iff$ $\exists E\in \mathbf{C}$ , $z'$ is one of the $b$ smallest roots ordered by magnitude of $f(z)-E=0$.

Prove or disprove: $P$ has a finite diameter.

Notes for clarification:

1.For some fixed $E'$, let the roots of $f(z)-E'=0$ be $|z_1|\leq |z_2|\leq ...$, then $z_1,z_2 ...,z_b$ are in the set P.(Counting or not counting terms with same magnitude as $z_b$ does not affect the result) The full set $P$ would be the union of all these $z$ over all $E'$.

2.e.g. If $f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$, P would be the unit circle and its interior.

My numerical checks show that it is always finite, but I haven't figured out a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=R(z)+Q(z)/z^b, \deg Q \le b-1, Q(0) \ne 0, \deg R =a$. For $E \ne 0$ the equation $f(z)=E$ is equivalent to $z^b-\frac{z^bR(z)+Q(z)}{E}=0$ since $Q(0)\ne 0$ so $z=0$ is not a root of the latter.

Let $M=\max_{|z|=1}|z^bR(z)+Q(z)|$ then by Rouche for $E>M$ we have that the equation has precisely as many roots as $z^b=0$ inside the unit circle so  $b$ roots have modulus bounded by $1$.

Since for $E \le M$ we can write the equation as $z^bR(z)+Q(z)-Ez^b=\sum a_mz^m=0, m=a+b, a_m \ne 0$ fixed, we see that the highest root is bounded by the positive root of the associated Cauchy polynomial $|a_m|z^m-\sum_{k \le m-1}|a_k|z^k$ which have uniformly bounded roots since the coefficients are uniformly bounded and $a_m$ is fixed, so we are done and the set $P$ is indeed bounded