Connected distribution of roots of Laurent polynomial
Consider a Laurent polynomial given by
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{i=-b}^{a}c_{i}z^{i}; a,b\in \mathbb{N}; c_{a},c_{-b}\neq 0
\end{equation}
and the equation
\begin{equation}
f(z)=E
\end{equation}
now we order its roots by magnitude as $|z_{1}(E)|\geq |z_{2}(E)|\geq ...$
Let the set $S_{i}$ be the set of all possible $z_{i}$ 's when $E$ takes every value in $\mathbb{C}$.
We notice the interior of different $S_{i}$ do not intersect, since for each $z$, $f(z)=E$ can only take one single value.
Prove or disprove the conjectures (separately):

$S_{a}$ and $S_{a+1}$ are connected.

2.$\forall k \exists r,r\exp(ik)\in S_{a/a+1}$.
Below is a calculated example for $a=2,b=2$. $S_{1-4}$ are in red, purple, blue, black.


I noticed that the second conjecture could be proved if one can show that there exists a neighborhood of the origin such that the neighborhood is a subset of S_(a+b) i.e. the smallest S_i. Anyone try to get this?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866951/about-root-distribution-of-complex-polynomial  this other post may help; be aware of the different notations.

I noticed that any path connecting points in S_i and S_(i+2) should go past S_(i+1)

Turned out that I shall do it myself. Here I use results from the other post to prove conj. 2 and provide some useful stuff related to conj.1.
We have some lemmata.
Lemma (1). Given points $p\in S_{j}$ and $q\in S_{j+2}$, $\forall$ Jordan arc $J$ connecting $p,q$, $J\cap S_{j+1}\neq \emptyset$.
Proof. Case 1: Suppose $(J\cap(\cup_{1\leq i\leq j}S_{i}))\cap(J\cap(\cup_{(j+2)\leq i\leq (a+b)}S_{i}))=\emptyset$. Since $\cup S_{i}=\mathbb{C}$ and $J$ is connected, the rest parts of $J$ must be in $S_{j+1}$.
Case 2. Consider the set given by $(J\cap(\cup_{1\leq i\leq j}S_{j}))\cap(J\cap(\cup_{(j+2)\leq i\leq (a+b)}S_{i}))\neq \emptyset$. By definition, points in this set are given by $|z_{j}|=|z_{j+2}|$ and hence must also be equal to $|z_{j+1}|$.
Lemma (2). There exists a neighborhood $N_0$ of $0$ s.t. $N_0\subset \cup_{(a+1)\leq i\leq b}S_{i}$.
Proof. See the other post. Replace $f(z)$ by $f(1/z)$ and we are done.
Lemma (3). If $S_{a}$ is connected for all $f(z)$, then $S_{a+1}$ is also connected.
Proof. Replacing $f(z)$ by $f(1/z)$ preserves the connectedness property.
Lemma 3 allows working on a bounded set for conj.1.
And we prove conj.2 below.
Consider the half line $\{r\exp(ik),r\in \mathbb{R}^+\}$ for some fixed $k$.
By lemma 2, it starts somewhere in $\cup_{(a+1)\leq i\leq (a+b)}S_{i}$ and ends in $\cup_{1\leq i\leq a}S_{i}$. By lemma 1, this half line must have nonempty intersection with both $S_{a}$ and $S_{a+1}$. Since this works for every $k$, we are done.
PS: Hope someone can prove conj.1 and take the bounty.
